# Proof of a Limit

Tags: real-analysis

Using only the formal definition of convergence prove that:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\cos^2(n^2+1)}{n+1} = 0$$

Workings:

$\left|\frac{\cos^2(n^2+1)}{n+1} - 0\right|$

$ = \left|\frac{\cos^2(n^2+1)}{n+1}\right|$

$ = \frac{\cos^2(n^2+1)}{n+1}$

$ < \frac{\cos^2(n^2+1)}{n}$

Now I'm not to sure on what to do next. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just use $|\cos(x)| \leq 1$

Comment: L'Hopital is allowed?

Comment: I can't use L'Hoptial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$0 \le \frac{\cos^2(n^2 + 1)}{n + 1} \le \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: I was thinking about $\frac{1}{n}$ but for some reason I thought $cos^2(n^2+1) > 1$. Thanks.